# Connection on the cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections

I'm reading "Differential forms and connections" by R. Darling and I must have made a mistake in problem 4 in section 9.4. It states:

> Prove that $\nabla_X \omega := \iota_X\, d\omega$ is *not* a connection on the cotangent bundle.

But it's additive in both arguments and $\nabla_{hX} \omega = \iota_{hX}\, d\omega = h\iota_{X}\, d\omega=h\nabla_X \omega$. The only problem can be the Leibniz rule:

$$\nabla_X (h\omega) = \iota_X\, d(h\omega)=\iota_X\, (dh\, \wedge\, \omega + h\,d\omega)=X(h)\, \omega + h\, \iota_x\,d\omega = h\nabla_X\omega + X(h)\omega,$$

so it's seems to work as well. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a missing term in the penultimate expression in your display equation.

Since $\iota_X$ is an antiderivation and $dh$ is a $1$-from, expanding the quantity $$\iota_X (\color{#df0000}{dh \wedge \omega} + \color{#0000df}{h \,d\omega})$$ gives
$$\color{#df0000}{(\iota_X dh) \wedge \omega - dh \wedge \iota_X d\omega} + \color{#0000df}{h \iota_X d\omega}.$$
By definition the first term is $X(h) \omega$ and the last is $h \nabla_X \omega$.